# how to scale up and down a shape based on mouseX and mouseY

Tags: createjs

createjs noob here,

I am trying to make a class, that when you pass in a shape, it lets you scale an object up or down based on mouse position.

```
beeSyrup.Scaler = function(obj){
        console.log("hi from scaler");
        if (not(obj) || !obj.on) return;
        obj.addEventListener("pressmove", function(e){
            obj.cursor = "alias";
            mouseX = e.stageX;
            mouseY = e.stageY;
            var lastMouseX = mouseX;
            var lastMouseY = mouseY;
            if (lastMouseX < mouseX && lastMouseY < mouseY){
                obj.scaleX += .1;
                obj.scaleY += .1;
            }else{
                obj.scaleX -= .1;
                obj.scaleY -= .1;
            }
            stage.update(); 
        });
    }
```

Currently this will scale it down once, but once it scales down you can only scale up. How would the correct if statement logic work?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `mouseX` and `lastMouseX` are always equal, because you are setting `lastMouseX = mouseX` before comparing them (true of the `Y` values as well). As such, the `else` condition is always satisfied, so it will always scale down.

There are many other things you will likely want to change to make this work in an user-friendly manner, but this is your immediate problem.

Here's a very rough JSFiddle to get you started down the right path: http://jsfiddle.net/9zu9jpvx/

Comment: Yes, I could feel that was a flawed logic.  I should know but I forget how to go about capturing the lastMouseX for the purposes of comparing it to the current one in my if statement

Comment: Generally you would use a `mousedown` event to grab the initial stageX/Y values, then compare against them in `pressmove`.